# How to disable right click on rdlc report

Tags: vb.net, rdlc

I am creating an RDLC report. The report looks pretty well in print layout mode. I set it to printlayout mode like this -

```
Me.ReportViewer1.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout)
```

Well, this is fine but if user right clicks on the report he get an option to disable this print layout mode as shown in the image below

[image: Look this image]

**and if the user disables the printLayout the reports get aligned to left side as shown in the below image**

[image: Problem Image]

> So, what I want to do is either disable the right click or if possible align the report properly on the default mode too.According to me, it is better to disable the right click because the report is always going to be generated in A4 format. Any help is appreciated, suggestions too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *right-click* menu is called a ContextMenu and the 
[ReportViewer.ShowContextMenu Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms253842%28v%3dvs.90%29) allows you to disable it.

```
Me.ReportViewer1.ShowContextMenu = False
```